# What would be a better solution, chained tasks or directly calling python functions?

Tags: python, celery

I am developing a pipeline where I have to complete several steps sequentially.

I have 6 tasks, 1 of them is optional. I will name them like so: `A, B, C(optional), D, E, F`

The return of the task A will be used in B (and same goes until the end):

`A-->B-->(check if it needs to go to C if not goes directly to D)-->C/D-->E-->F`

What would be a better solution, should very task(function) be a celery task or should I just call them one after another in my python code like:

```py
# ... and so on with the tasks

def task_B(args):
    # processing
    task_C(processed_args_from_task_B) # and so on.

@celery_app.task
def task_A():
    # processing
    task_B(args)


# OR 
# ... and so on with the tasks

@celery_app.task
def task_B(json_args):
    return processed_json_args
    

@celery_app.task
def task_A():
    # processing
    chain(task_B.s(json_args), task_C.s()).apply_async() # and so on
```

What I see as an advantage is better debugging from task to task (the celery tasks solution) but  the python direct calling method is definitely more easy.

Note: I strictly need those tasks sequentially no need for async since that every function/task is depending on previous return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases (you didn't explain enough about yours)- **wrap everything in one task wins**, some reasons:

1. Less running overhead.
2. Anyway you can (and should) track everything with logging.
3. Handle complicated task dependency chains easily with python code.
4. Optionally migrate this code to other orchestration tools without marrying celery.

You can find some cases with more justification for separation- maybe for longer tasks, managing python dependencies between tasks, run tasks in parallel (not your case) or for higher orchestration needs like apache Airflow.

Comment: My last solution, before thinking of chains was everything wrapped under 1 task plus logging every task. I am running long running tasks (in the most complex case it can take up to 6 hours, the main task is simply recording a stream of data before further processing). The reason why I am not using Airflow is because I need the Django ORM + some other packages and as far as I know the workarounds in airflow are too many to use those packages, that's why I went with celery. Anyway thanks for your input, I think that I am gonna go with single task solution.